# How to create a TLS 1.3 CertificateVerify message with OpenSSL in C/C++?

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa, handshake, tls1.3

I need to implement the TLS 1.3 protocol myself, using OpenSSL just as crypto-backend. I got stuck at server CertificateVerify message - can't figure out how to create it. Here is a [code and some files at git](https://github.com/EugeneIceman/SignRSA) (single cpp-file, 216 lines of code, but just focus at `main()`). All binary messages in "files" folder are made by openssl s_server application and there is also reference CertificateVerify message, which I need to reproduce manualy using openssl functions (see comment in code).

Help me please to build a valid callstack of openssl methods to make "my CertificateVerify" match to the reference one (and to learn how the RSA-PSS works).

Comment: For what purpose? What security and code reviews will be performed before your code will be used? How many years are you planning to support your TLS implementation? As you can see implementing TLS on your own is a bad idea especially when it will be used later in devices accessible via Internet.

Comment: @Robert, To use it in my projects. OpenSSL's protocol implementation has one disadvantage - it requires to allocate new `SSL_CTX` for each session and free it with all associated BIO buffers. It has no ability to reuse previously allocated structures for other sessions. I don't like it and want my servers to be more efficient in network I/O and security

Comment: OpenSSL is not the only available TLS implementation. Before starting to re-implement something that is highly security critical please always check alternatives. There is for example Google's OpenSSL fork BoringSSL or GnuTLS.

Comment: I found it in OpenSSL sources. The answer is [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/ssl/statem/statem_lib.c#L272)